# kendo ui grid sort partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a main view with 3 partial views in. One of the partial views contain a kendo grid which should be sortable.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("tasksgrid")
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100%; font-size:14px;" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.Url).Title("URL").Hidden();
        columns.Bound(e => e.Id).Title("ID").Hidden();

        columns.Template(@<img src="@item.OperatorCreated.ImageSource" style="width:80px;height:80px;"/>).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(100).Title("Picture");
        columns.Bound(e => e.Subject).Template(@<div>
            <div style="font-size: 20px;">@item.OperatorCreated.Name</div>
            <div>@item.Subject<br />@item.Message</div>
        </div>).Title("Details").HtmlAttributes(new {id = "detailcolumn"});
        columns.Bound(e => e.DateTimeCreated).Title("Date").Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "datecolumn" });
    })        
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Server()
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        )
    .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
    .Scrollable()
)
```

This partial view is only rendered when a certain action in the other view is selected. Which then retrieves data to fill the grid.

```
function RefreshTasks(name) {
    var serviceUrl = "/Tasks/PopulateTasks?actionname=" + name;
    var request = $.post(serviceUrl);

    request.done(
        function (data) {
            $("#tasks").html(data);
        }
    );
}
```

When sorting is done on the grid the following url is created
"localhost:1772/?tasksgrid-sort=DateTimeCreated-desc&tasksgrid-group=&tasksgrid-filter="
which refreshes the whole page meaning my partial view with the grid isn't there anymore.

Is there a way to throw this url into the partial view only.

I found a way to do exactly what I needed for this implementation.

```
$("#tasksgrid .k-link").click(function (e) {//call the function when column header is clicked
    var thelink = e.target.href;//get the url that would be navigated to on sort

    var serviceUrl = thelink;
    var request = $.post(serviceUrl);//post the url

    request.done(
        function (data) {
            $("#tasks").html(data);//update div
        }
    );

    return false;//cancels navigation
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the grid to use Ajax binding. Otherwise it will refresh the whole page. More info is available in the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding).